# how to integrate a potential function?

Tags: integration

I'm not getting integrate of this please help me. I started learning it not too long ago. then I'm not able to solve this yet. but I really need it

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Comment: Look at equation$(5)$ here ... http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseSine.html

Comment: youre right. but I don't want to salve by trigonometric funcion. I know this result in arcsen(x)

Comment: are you asking for the answer or how to solve it?
 either way ... https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F+(1-x%5E2)%5E(1%2F2)

Comment: *"I don't want to solve by trigonometric function"* Does that mean you cannot substitute the following?
$$x=\sin(u) \implies dx=\cos(u)~du$$
If you are not familiar with integration by substitution, see [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/integration-by-substitution.html).

Comment: Well considering the answer by its own nature involves trig' functions, I don't know how you wanna avoid them.

Comment: is there anyother way not involving trig' functions?

Answer (score 3):

Recall the formula for a circle:

$$x^2+y^2=1$$

Solving for the upper half of the circle in terms of $x$,

$$y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

Now recall the formula for arc-length:

$$\operatorname{arc length}_{a,b}(f)=\int_a^b\sqrt{1+[f'(x)]^2}~\mathrm dx$$

Thus, the arc-length of a circle is given by

$$\begin{align}\operatorname{arc length}_{a,b}(\text{circle})&=\int_a^b\sqrt{1+[y'(x)]^2}~\mathrm dx\\&=\int_a^b\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}}~\mathrm dx\\&=\int_a^b\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2+x^2}{1-x^2}}~\mathrm dx\\&=\int_a^b\sqrt{\frac1{1-x^2}}~\mathrm dx\\&=\int_a^b\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}~\mathrm dx\end{align}$$

Thus, it happens to be the case that $f(x)$ is equivalent to the arc-length of a circle plus a constant of integration.  We may set $a=0$ for simplicity and letting $b$ be our variable:

$$f(x)=\operatorname{arc length}_{0,x}(\text{circle})+C$$

The following red arc represents what we want to find:

[image]

Via some trigonometry, we find the purple angle is $\theta_x=\frac\pi2-\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x\right)$, and since the circumference of the full circle is $2\pi$, we derive that

$$f(x)=\theta_x+C=\frac\pi2-\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x\right)+C$$

> $$f(x)=C^\star-\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x\right)$$

which holds for $x\in[0,1]$ and is equivalent to

$$f(x)=C^\star+\arcsin(x)$$

Comment: I understand that very well. But I want to know how was created the funcion arcsin()! why just calculators can resolve trigonometric functions?

Comment: Check your grammar, your message is a little unclear.  As my answer tried to emphasize, the trigonometry comes in necessarily due to the geometric interpretation of an integral, particularly the arc-length formula here.